# Charging capacitors with computer power supply?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor

I am an AP Physics student in high school, and I am in a group that is doing a project that will involve a bank of capacitors taken out of used disposable cameras hooked up in parallel.  We need to charge the capacitors.  My friend had an idea of charging them with a power supply taken out of a computer.  I am wondering: is this safe and will it work?  The power supply is rated at 115 and 230 volts; the capacitors are averaging 100 micro farads and 330-440 volts.

Comment: Slow charge is best. Look into resistors to slow the charge rate. Safety is a relative term.

Comment: You can only get 24V out of a computer supply. More if you're smart^H^H^H^H^Hcrazy.

Answer (score 3):

A computer power supply is really not suitable for charging photo flash capacitors to near working voltage. It may be safe, if you use a series resistor to limit the current and take care as to the polarity(!), but it won't charge them to anywhere near full voltage, and since energy is proportional to voltage squared, the energy storage will be very low.

Charging photo flash capacitors to near working voltage, particularly in parallel or series groups, is not a suitable project safety-wise for high school students, particularly unsupervised, no matter what some of us may or may not have survived in our youth.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we all survived it. Not always unscathed though...

Comment: I learned to keep my left arm behind my back thanks to a photo flash cap.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, using a computer power supply is not what I would call safe in this situation, because it may produce very high currents before fusing.  However, it is definitely doable.

In order to answer precisely you question: go to [ATX power supply on wikipédia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#Power_supply) and take a look at the connector.  In order to start the power supply, you need to short the pin #16 [Power_ON] to ground.  The power supply pulls high that pin to 5V, so shorting it will cause the power supply to start.

Even when short that pin, the power supply may refuse to start.  This is due to the fact that it is an SMPS (switch mode power supply) and therefore requires a minimal load to start on every power rail (typically 3.3V, 5V and 12V rails must be loaded enough).  Other rails (-12V, -5V, etc) may not need to be loaded.  The amount of current that you need to draw is usually quite high, which is the reason why using a computer power supply is not that much safe.  You need big resistors of 1-5 Ohm with power ratings up to 15W.  I won't list expected loads, because it depends on design and therefore on your very power supply.  Sometimes it is listed on the power supply, but most of the time, manufacturers expect your computer to sink enough current for the PSU to boot.

If you do not want high current nor perfectly regulated voltage, you may use the POWER_GOOD pin as a 5V source.  I do not recommend this.  Also, do not forget to use a fuse in series with whatever pin you use in order to protect yourself in the event you short it with the ground pin.

Sincerely, you may well use a 9V battery to charge your capacitor.  You took them of a camera which was battery powered, so it will work and it will be much safer.  A 100µF capacitor is quite a small one, so you should be able to charge it many times with your 9V battery before it depletes. (Like 10'000 of times...)

I don't know what you want to do with your capacitor, but never forget to put a resistor in series with it to avoid high inrush current which could cause it to break or explode.

Here is a safe capacitor charging circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBNlrh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Voltage as a function of time is given by expression :
V(t) = 1/C * int[ I(t) ] dt + V0

Or more simply:

Charge time ~= 5*R*C

In the example circuit, it would take approximately 0,05s to reach 99,3% of maximum charge.

Comment: You've neglected that the voltage rating of the capacitors is significantly higher than 9V. The energy storage ability of the capacitors will be wasted in such a configuration.

Comment: Yes, but 9V/330V = 2,72%; while with 24V (maximum of computer SMPS) 24V/330V = 7,2%.  In either case, it will have crappy energy storage.  Also, the OP didn't specify whether they chose those capacitor for they specifications or because they actually salvaged them.  The idea of using a computer SMPS (max 24V) hinted me that it was more likely that he salvaged them...

Comment: At worst, he may stack up dozens of 9V batteries in series if he needs such high voltages.  It will be safe and easy to do.

Comment: In what way is stacking dozens of 9V batteries safe? I can't imagine a situation where a high school student has created a 216V+ battery as being something I wouldn't cross the street to put a stop to.

Comment: We actually built a large tesla coil with 1m electrical arcs when I was in high school.  It means ~3MV electrical arcs.  We had planned our setup so it could be started from 4 meters away, there was a no man zone around the device while it was operating.  It is not dangerous if they do it safely and under tight supervision.  Anyway, OP didn't say that they actually wanted to charge them up to 300V.

Comment: OP did say the power supply is "rated for" 115 and 230 V, which in this context suggests to me that OP: 1) doesn't understand electronics that well and 2) is looking to do something dangerous without supervision, because the input rating on the power supply has no bearing on the use of the output to charge the capacitors.

Comment: That is true, but a relative of I already asked if it was really safe to plug a 115V rated device in a "120V" plug we have home.  Yes that person doesn't understand, but should I say: ok don't try to build your computer it is too dangerous.  Also, if the OP really wants to do it, it will do it whatever we say.  I prefer to tell him to not do it, but if it ever do it, use 9V battery instead of using mains because it is less likely that he dies from 9V batteries than from the mains.  Also, will he really buy 30 batteries???

Comment: Now that being said, I do not totally agree with you, but I will stop arguing, because you are right about the the most important point: they may do something dangerous and I don't want to be the one that encouraged them to do something that could injury them without *proper supervision*.